# Event when useRef element have height more than zero

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, use-ref

I have big list of photo thumbnails, and I should be able to scroll one of thumbnails into view when list is loaded.

Photos are populated with `map` function, and one of the thumbnails' container div will be given `ref`.

I tried useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (scrollRef.current && scrollRef.current instanceof HTMLDivElement) {
        scrollRef.current.scrollIntoView({
            behavior: 'auto',
            block: 'center',
            inline: 'center',
        });
    }
}, [scrollRef.current]);
```

Problem is that `ref` or `ref.current` cannot be used as dependency list of useEffect. I get warning:

> React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency:
> 'scrollRef.current'. Either exclude it or remove the dependency array.
> Mutable values like 'scrollRef.current' aren't valid dependencies
> because mutating them doesn't re-render the component

How can I fire useEffect or some other function when `ref.current` changes? And by changes, I mean specifically its clientHeight value changes. Because initially it is zero, and `scrollIntoView` does not work yet.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [callback ref](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs).

```
function Example() {
    const [divRef, setDivRef] = useState(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (divRef && divRef.clientHeight > 0) {
            div.scrollIntoView({
                behavior: 'auto',
                block: 'center',
                inline: 'center',
            });
        }
    }, [divRef]);

    return <div ref={setDivRef} />;
}
```